# Manager dictionary very slow for updating values from 100+ processes

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-multiprocessing

I am having a hard time working with Python multiprocessing module.

In a nutshell, I have a dictionary object which updates, say, occurrences of a string from lots of s3 files. The key for the dictionary is the occurrence I need which increments by 1 each time it is found.

Sample code:

```
import boto3
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import simplejson

client = boto3.client('s3')
occurences_to_find = ["occ1", "occ2", "occ3"]

list_contents = []


def getS3Key(prefix_name, occurence_dict):
    kwargs = {'Bucket': "bucket_name", 'Prefix': "prefix_name"}
    while True:
        value = client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        try:
            contents = value['Contents']
            for obj in contents:
                key=obj['Key']
                yield key
            try:
                kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = value['NextContinuationToken']
            except KeyError:
                break
        except KeyError:
            break

def getS3Object(s3_key, occurence_dict):
    object = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key)
    objjects = object['Body'].read()
    for object in objects:
        object_json = simplejson.loads(activity)
        msg = activity_json["msg"]
        for occrence in occurence_dict:
            if occrence in msg:
                occurence_dict[str(occrence)] += 1
                break

'''each process will hit this function'''
def doWork(prefix_name_list, occurence_dict):
    for prefix_name in prefix_name_list:
        for s3_key in getS3Key(prefix_name, occurence_dict):
            getS3Object(s3_key, occurence_dict)


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    '''shared dictionary between processes'''
    occurence_dict = manager.dict()
    procs = []
    s3_prefixes = [["prefix1"], ["prefix2"], ["prefix3"], ["prefix4"]]
    for occurrence in occurences_to_find:
        occurence_dict[occurrence] = 0

    for index,prefix_name_list in enumerate(s3_prefixes):
        proc = Process(target=doWork, args=(prefix_name_list, occurence_dict))
        procs.append(proc)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print(occurence_dict)

main()
```

I am having issues with speed of the code as it takes hours for the code to run with more than 10000 s3 prefixes and keys. I think the manager dictionary is shared and is locked by each process, and hence, it is not being updated concurrently; rather one process waits for it to be "released".

How can I update the dictionary parallely? Or, how can I maintain multiple dicts for each process and then combine the result in the end?

Comment: could you create an empty list at the onset, then during each run, populate a single dictionary and add this to the list. At the end, take this list and iterate over its dictionaries to update a new master dictionary.

Comment: Are you really launching 100 processes? You should not really exceed CPU core count -1. You've got a lot of overhead with that many processes

Comment: how fast do you want? have you done any benchmark?

Comment: @JacobIRR: Is there a way I can leverage queue/pools for this task? I'm very new to multithreaded programming so have no clue. What you're saying is achievable though.

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes I am, but half of it gets killed at the beginning few minutes of the program. I have a new process for each "prefix".